# Print one array element into another array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to print one list of array element to another array element from the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>
var juice = [];
var fruits = [2, 5, 7, 10,15, 25,28,34,38,45,49,52,55,57,59];
for(int i =0;i < fruits.length;i++){
            juice[i] = fruits[i];
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = juice.length;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = juice;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the output from the above code.

Comment: oldArray? where have you defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  <script>
  var juice = [];
  var fruits = [2, 5, 7, 10,15, 25,28,34,38,45,49,52,55,57,59];
  for(var i =0;i < fruits.length;i++){
              juice[i] = fruits[i];
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = juice.length;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = juice;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have two errors:

- one with wrong variable declaration

  ```
  for(int i =0;i < oldArray.length;i++){
  //  ^^^
  ```
- and the second with the wrong varible for the length

  ```
  for (int i =0;i < oldArray.length;i++){
  //                ^^^^^^^^
  ```

```js
var juice = [],
    fruits = [2, 5, 7, 10, 15, 25, 28, 34, 38, 45, 49, 52, 55, 57, 59];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    juice[i] = fruits[i];
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = juice.length;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = juice;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice()` to copy arrays:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var 
            juice = [],
            fruits = [2, 5, 7, 10, 15, 25, 28, 34, 38, 45, 49, 52, 55, 57, 59];

        juice = fruits.slice();

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = juice.length;
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = juice;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

[Official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

`int i` - it was copied NOT from JS code, and `oldArray` is not defined, you have error in console. 
try:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>
var juice = [];
var fruits = [2, 5, 7, 10,15, 25,28,34,38,45,49,52,55,57,59];
for(var i =0;i < fruits.length;i++){
            juice[i] = fruits[i];
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = juice.length;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = juice;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.s. next time try not to use ctrl+c ctrl+v